# Inject URL parameters into Zend_Navigation menu

Tags: php, zend-framework

Is anyone using Zend Navigation in conjunction with URLs that require dynamic parameters?

Zend_Navigation seems really easy when dealing with static routes, but I can't figure out any way to make it play nice with dynamic URL parameters.

A route like:

```
routes.editUser.route = '/users/:id/edit'
routes.editUser.defaults.controller = 'user'
routes.edutUser.defaults.action = 'edit'
```

In this navigation:

```
<pages>
  <editUser>
    <controller>users</controller>
    <action>edit</action>
    <route>editUser</route>
  </editUser>
</pages>
```

Just throws an error in Zend_Navigation unless I specify a default value for `:id`. However, it is no use to me if I can't inject the actual user id when the menu is constructed.

Is there a straightforward way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`resources.navigation.pages.profile.params_id = "USER_ID"`

```
// Looks for any navigation pages requiring user information and injects it
$pages = $this->getContainer()->findAllBy('params_id', 'USER_ID');
foreach($pages as &$page){
    $page->setParams(array(
        'id'=>$user->id,
        'username'=>$user->username
    ));
}
```